# How to speed up the following code using numba? Numba Warning: The size argument is not supported in the following functions

Tags: python, performance, cython, numba

I really want to speed up the code below by Numba. But I notice that Numba does not support generate normal distribution with size like `np.random.normal(size=(nprime, nprime))`. Is there any alternative way to speed up my code below? I also have tried with Cython but the improvement is small.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def simulate_f(n):
    nprime = n - 1  # adjust because of centerlization
    main = np.sqrt(2) * np.random.normal(size=(1, nprime))
    off = np.random.normal(size=(nprime, nprime))
    tril = np.tril(off, -1)
    W_n = tril + tril.T
    np.fill_diagonal(W_n, main)

    eigenvalues = LA.eigvals(W_n)
    w = np.flip(np.sort(eigenvalues))
    # GOE_L12_dist[:,i] = w[0:2]
    return w[0:2]


def GOE_L12_sim_jb(n, rep):
    GOE_0 = Parallel(n_jobs=8,)(delayed(simulate_f)(n) for i in range(rep))
    GOE = np.sort(np.array(GOE_0).T, axis=0)[::-1]
    return GOE

%time _ = GOE_L12_sim_jb(200, 100)
```

Output

```
CPU times: user 134 ms, sys: 11.2 ms, total: 146 ms
Wall time: 338 ms
```

I run the code from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72582850/14277722) to a previous question as below with Numba, but there is no improvement for the speed

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(n):
    nprime = n-1
    main = np.sqrt(2.) * np.random.normal(0., 1., (nprime))
    off = np.random.normal(0., 1., (nprime, nprime))
    tril = np.tril(off, -1)
    W_n = tril + tril.T
    np.fill_diagonal(W_n, main)

    eigenvalues = LA.eigvals(W_n)
    return np.flip(np.sort(eigenvalues))


def GOE_L12_sim_jb(n, rep):
    GOE_0 = Parallel(n_jobs=8,)(delayed(func)(n) for i in range(rep))
    GOE = np.flip(np.sort(np.array(GOE_0).T, axis=0), axis=0)
    return GOE

%time _ = GOE_L12_sim_jb(200, 100)
```

Output after compilation

```
CPU times: user 123 ms, sys: 11.5 ms, total: 135 ms
Wall time: 320 ms
```

Comment: Please attribute code snippets to conform to the current SO [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) and to make the context clear. I added the attribution to the question.

Comment: As it is now, the question contains two different problems. How to prevent the warning was already covered in the previous question.